# Calculating Conditional Expected Value in R

Tags: r, conditional-expectation, random-walk

I have a stock whose returns follows a Random Walk with

```
mu= 6% and sigma= 20%
```

I would like to calculate the 10 returns of this distribution that I would get with equal probability (10%).

Comment: Generally one does "this" ( since I understand the question to be defining a distribution on a restricted range, although it is not completely clear to my reading at the moment) by defining a function using the density of the underlying distribution (i.e. its PDF) and dividing by the difference between the CDF evaluated at its endpoints for the range of the "conditional" distribution.

Comment: Furthermore: As long as you persist in specifying simultaneously  4 parameters for a two parameter distribution (the lognormal) , it will be difficult to deliver a sensible answer. You should also look at the documentation for `?Lognormal` and agree with @IceCreamToucan that this needs methodological clarification before attempts at coding.

Comment: The deciles are properties of the distribution.  Please explain, then, what you mean by their "conditional expected value."

Comment: @whuber i adjusted my question. It didn’t make any sense beforehand.

Comment: See the help for `qnorm.`